# Regex/PHP check if group of characters appears only once

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am trying to validate an input in PHP with REGEX. I want to check whether the input has the `%s` character group inside it and that it appears only once. Otherwise, the rule should fail.

Here's what I've tried:

`preg_match('|^[0-9a-zA-Z_-\s:;,\.\?!\(\)\p{L}(%s){1}]*$|u', $value);` (there are also some other rules besides this; I've tried the `(%s){1}` part and it doesn't work).

I believe it is a very easy solution to this, but I'm not really into REGEX's...Thank you for your help!

Comment: Given your own answer, I'd suggest that the title of this question is incorrect.

Comment: Changed the title in order to reflect my answer also.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, you need a positive lookahead.  The lookahead causes the expression to only match if it finds a single %s.

```
preg_match('|^(?=[^%s].*?[%s][^%s]*$)[0-9a-zA-Z_-\s:;,\.\?!\(\)\p{L}(%s){1}]*$|u', $value);
```

I'll explain how each part works

`^(?=[^%s].*?[%s][^%s]*$)` is a zero-width assertion -- `(?=regex)` a positive lookahead -- (meaning it must match, but does not "eat" any characters).  It means that the whole line can have only 1 `%s`.

`[0-9a-zA-Z_-\s:;,\.\?!\(\)\p{L}(%s){1}]*$` The remaining part of the regex also looks at the entire string and ensures that the whole string is composed only of the characters in the character class (like your original regex).

Comment: Can you please explain what does the code you have added? It seems pretty complicated :)

Comment: @linkyndy, I've added an explanation.  Please don't hesitate to ask for further clarification if need be.  good luck.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It seems clearer now, but still I believe I need practice with REGEX's. Therefore I will stick to the `substr_count()` solution for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this with PHP's [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) function, following **Johnsyweb** suggestion to use an alternate way to perform the validation and because the REGEX's suggested seem pretty complicated.

Thank you again!

Comment: That is far better than my answer! I'm not a PHP developer, I just stumbled across this question as it was tagged [regex].

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `preg_match_all` with your pattern and check the number of matches.  If it's 1, then you're ok - something like this:

```
$result = (preg_match_all('|^[0-9a-zA-Z_-\s:;,\.\?!\(\)\p{L}(%s){1}]*$|u', $value) == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'|^(?=(?:(?!%s).)*%s(?:(?!%s).)*$)[0-9_\s:;,.?!()\p{L}-]+$|u'
```

The `(%s){1}` sequence inside the square brackets probably doesn't do what you think it does, but never mind, the solution is more complex.  In fact, `{1}` should never appear anywhere in a regex.  It doesn't ensure that there's only one of something, as many people assume.  As a matter of fact, it doesn't do *anything*; it's pure clutter.

---

EDIT (in answer to the comment): To ensure that only one of a particular sequence is present in a string, you have to actively examine every single character, classifying it as either part-of-`%s` or *not* part-of-`%s`.  To that end, `(?:(?!%s).)*` consumes one character at a time, *after* the negative lookahead has confirmed that the character is not the start of `%s`.

When that part of the lookahead expression quits matching, the next thing in the string has to be `%s`.  Then the second `(?:(?!%s).)*$` kicks in to confirm that there are no more `%s` sequences until the end of the string.

And don't forget that the lookahead expression *must* be anchored at both ends.  Because the lookahead is the first thing after the main regex's start anchor you don't need to add another `^`.  But the lookahead *must* end with its own `$` anchor.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain a little bit what does all that sequence before my existing regex? I thought it would be a simple solution, but it seems utterly complicated.

Comment: Okay, I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Oh, so it isn't very easy, but I think I managed to understand the idea. Thanks for clarifying. I definitely need some more practice with REGEX's...But until then, I will stick with the solution with the `substr_count()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not "into" regular expressions, why not solve this with PHP?

One call to the builtin [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.strpos.php) will tell you if the string has a match. A second call will tell you if it appears more than once.

This will be easier for you to read and for others to maintain.

Comment: My whole validation consists of regex's and I wanted to have each rule under a single line rather than spread out in several blocks of code.

Comment: That's what *functions* are for!